# Is output of debugClientLibs flag cached in CQ/AEM

Tags: caching, aem, client-library

I've been using debugClientLibs flag in my AEM pages, (helpful for debugging clientlibs related issues) like this `localhost:4502/content/geometrixx/en.html?debugClientLibs=true`.

Recently, I was seeing some caching related issue of JS. I noticed, when using debugClientLibs flag, `no-cache` header was not included in Request Header of individual JS files.

It does not make sense to cache these individual files as they would defeat the purpose of debugging clientlibs(i would not want to see the cached JS and CSS files when i'm using debugClientLibs flag in my pages). Attaching a screentshot of Request and Response headers i got.

[image: Request and Response Headers]

My Question here is:
**Are these individual clientlib files cached on the browser ?**

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - it depends.

Every browser has its own implementation for networking & caching rules.  Response headers are hints to the browser to help them be more efficient.  But the browsers may chose to do its own thing.  Even more distracting, the behavior may change between versions of a given browser.  Further, even if the browser's default behavior is to follow (or ignore) such headers, the user may configure different behavior.  So don't assume anything, especially globally.